# Kafka mqtt-connector over TLS

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, mqtt

I need help because I'm new about kafka and mqtt.
I'im using docker compose to create an architecture for the communication between Mosquitto broker and Kakfa

I'm also using the connector provided by confluent Kafka Connect MQTT (  https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-mqtt)

It work well for the commnunication over port 1883
but whe I tried to use MQTT connection over port 8883, it fails because it can't find any certificate.

Does anyone know how configure Kafka Connect MQTT? what kind of certificates are necessry (*.crt doesn't work)?

Thanks in advance,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit old but as I run into the same issue recently, I put the solution here in case it help someone in the future:

You have to create a TrustStore file using [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html) and put your certificate inside:

```
keytool -import -file C:\cascerts\CA.cert -alias CA -keystore myTrustStore
```

You will be prompt to set a password for the TrustStore.

Then in the MQTT connector properties file put the SSL config:

```
# SSL
mqtt.ssl.trust.store.path=myTrustStore
mqtt.ssl.trust.store.password=password
mqtt.ssl.key.store.path=myTrustStore
mqtt.ssl.key.store.password=password
```